# square matrices A and B have equal rows/colomns and A*B = I matrix does that mean that B*A also = I?

Tags: matrices

If you have two square matrices with equal rows and columns A and B and A*B = the identity matrix does that mean that B*A also equals the identity matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of the inverse, if

$$AB = I,$$

Where $I$ is the identity matrix,
This means that $B = A^{-1} \wedge A = B^{-1}$. If

$$BA \neq I \implies BB^{-1} \neq I \implies B \neq B,$$

which is a contradiction. Thus, $BA = I.$ And so $AB = I \implies BA = I.$